# how tosplit the string in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, substring

I have a string in a stored procedure:
suppose @V_str= HowAre_You?
I need _You value and store it in some variable. So my output should be @var_newstr=_You?

How to use substring function in stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? Did you check the available string functions? SO is a Q&A site about specific programming questions, not a cheat-sheet. Not my downvote by the way. There *are* a lot of duplicate questions though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - select substring of all characters following last hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656884/sql-server-select-substring-of-all-characters-following-last-hyphen)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the SUBSTRING() function in TSQL.  In this example, I find the _ character and get the _ and everything to the right.

```
DECLARE @V_str VARCHAR(100)= 'HowAre_You'
SELECT @var_newstr = SUBSTRING(@V_str, CHARINDEX('_',@V_str,0)+1,LEN(@V_str))
```

This should produce the result:

```
'_You'
```

Comment: Code-only answers that don't explain how the code works or why it answers the question are *not* considered good answers. Especially when they *don't* work. This code returns `You`, not `_You`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake,this code will get the desired  output
DECLARE @V_str VARCHAR(100) = 'HowAre_You?'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@V_str, CHARINDEX('_',@V_str,0),LEN(@V_str)) The charindex function will geive the postion of '_ 'in the string which will be passed as starting position for the substring function and len() will give the end position.