# Tsql remove all values left of char / , if char is present in a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column with possible values as "NA/ANN" or "system"
Now I want to get the contents of this string after /, if / is present.
If / is not present the string itself.

Result as  "ANN" and "system"

I tried

```
select LEFT(LogUser, CHARINDEX('\', LogUser)) from table1
```

but I get values before / and not after /

Comment: TRIM as the name says, trims. It nothing to do with splitting or finding a character in a string, or extracting a substring. Have you actually tried to solve this? Did you look at the [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Tried to us this but getting values before / and not after / 


select LEFT(LogUser, CHARINDEX('\', LogUser)) from table1

Comment: Why did you post about `TRIM` then? There are other methods that return substrings, including `SUBSTRING` and `RIGHT`. Post what you actually tried in the question

Comment: I was trying everything, TRIM i tried initially

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - select substring of all characters following last hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656884/sql-server-select-substring-of-all-characters-following-last-hyphen)

Comment: Did you actually read the function descriptions? `TRIM` has nothing to do with the problem. It *trims* characters from the start or end. You can't solve anything by trying things at random without even reading the labels. `RIGHT` works. `SUBSTRING` works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but saying `I tried everything` and then including an unrelated function sounds like no effort was made, just an attempt to evade the `what have you tried?` question. It has the opposite effect - it annoys people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many ways you can do this is as follows using a combination of standard string functions *right* and *charindex*; *Nulif* is used to handle when there are no delimiters at all.

```
declare @string varchar(50) = '123/xxyyy';

select Right(@string, IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex('/',Reverse(@string)),0)-1, Len(@string)));
```

Example [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FQsBaP9c)

Comment: @AnnSnow Are you actually using the code as shown above? For your example string it returns `ANN`, see [this demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FQsBaP9c)

Answer (score 0):

additional way:

```
declare @string varchar(50) = 'NA/ANN';

select parsename(replace(@string,'/','.'),1)
```

for cases when dots `.` after `/`:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50) = 'NA/ANN.ANNA';

SELECT  REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, '.', '|'), '/', '.'), 1), '|', '.');
```

Comment: this will not work if there is a dot `.` after `/` in the original string

Comment: @Squirrel yes, sure, but this will work if there is no a dot . after / in the original string ;) 
So, for OP (...with possible values as "NA/ANN") such approach is applicable.

Comment: Aside: [`ParseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is not a universal parser. For some examples of how well it works please see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tj2SmLDu). Playing games with `replace` to add/remove/swap periods (`.`) isn't a panacea. Ref: [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).